# Handling session value in select box FORM and PHP

Tags: php, forms, post, submit, session-variables

I have a form and table like this. 
What I'm trying to do is - If the select box is selected with a value, it is stored in session on submit(post) and i would like to retain the session value in select box.
If there is session value, it will display the session value in select box, else it will display all.
The below case is not working in my case.
What the below code do is - first time it doesn't set the session value. If I submit again(second time) the session is stored with the first value(first submit value) and it goes on like this.
Hope this question is answerable.

EDITED:

```
    <?php 
    session_start();
    if($_POST){ 
    $_SESSION['book_id'] = $_POST['book_id'];
    ?>
    <table class="table table-bordered" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    My Table Content
    </table>
    <?php } ?>

    <form method="post">
    <?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>
    <select name="book_id" class="form-control">
    <option value="0">Select Book</option>
    <?php while($row=mysql_fetch_array($book_query)){?>
    <option <?php if(isset($_SESSION['book_id']) && $row['book_id'] == $_SESSION['book_id']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> value="<?php  echo $row['book_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['book_name']; ?></option>
    <?php  }?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

EDIT:

I have print_r for the session value.
What happens is - When I submit the form first time, the session value is empty.
When I submit it second time, the first submit value is stored in session, and it goes on.

Thanks,
Kimz

Comment: did you add a some codes like "session_start();"?

Comment: session_start is there already ..i have declared that at top of my page.  i have not mentioned in this code. sorry

Comment: You should add your $_POST statement at the top of the page before the select box

Comment: 0603 -  i have done that also. check my edited code. and help me out !!!

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

It seems you are mixing up book_id and book_name.

Also, you don't seem to submit a "book_name" in your form.

The "if($_POST)"-block is executed when the page loads, and not when the form is sent. So essentially, you first try to select something by a value in your session, and then afterwards store said value into your session.

Comment: oops, check my question again, i have edited. typo. sorry for that.
could you help me now with my coding

Comment: I have print_r for the session value.
What happens is - When I submit the form first time, the session value is empty.
When I submit it second time, the first submit value is stored in session, and it goes on.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have session_start() included somewhere.

Secondly, try changing your IF on the options to this:

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['book_id']) && $row['book_id'] == $_SESSION['book_id']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>
```

Notice the isset. Without that on page load you are likely to get a PHP undefined index error.

Finally, try placing the 'if ($_POST) {}' before the form is displayed, so the session gets set before the form is displayed. Currently you wont see any changes until you refresh the page again, this is because the form is being rendered and then the session is set from the POST data afterwards.

Comment: i have tried all the three. it dn't work. help me out please.

Comment: Boreded - I have edited as you have mentioned. check my code again. it is not working again. could you check the same in ur machine

Comment: I have print_r for the session value.
What happens is - When I submit the form first time, the session value is empty.
When I submit it second time, the first submit value is stored in session, and it goes on.

Comment: I have tested your code and it works just fine. This is what happens for me: 1. print_r is empty -- 2. Submit form with id of 2 -- 3. Print_r now shows id = 2 saved in session and dropdown has id 2 selected -- 4. select id 4 and session updates to show id = 4 and 4 is now selected in the dropdown. Is this what you are seeing?